Proof that a normal ($T_4$) pseudocompact space is countably compact
I am having little trouble understanding the proof for this in Counterexamples in Topology (page 20). It is a proof by contradiction.
Suppose you have a you have normal pseudo compact space $X$ which isn't countably compact. It states then that $X$ contains an countable infinite subset $S=\{x_n\}$ (this was the notation that was used) which has no $\omega$-accumulation point. I'm following until this part since not being countably compact implies not being sequentially compact. But the next step states that $S$ is closed and has a discrete subspace topology, since $X$ is $T_1$. The following steps I understand with using Tietze extension to create an unbounded real valued continuous function and come to a contradiction.
But I really don't understand how come $S$ is closed and has a discrete topology. I know that a finite union of singletons in a $T_1$ space is closed but I don't see how this is the case for an infinite union?

This seems to be false, see the counter examples listed here

@SoumikMukherjee its true if you assume normal to mean that the space is Hausdorff and any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by disjoint neighbourhoods. That is, $T_4$ on pi-base

Al those example aren’t $T_1$ our definition of normal and the one used in the book includes that.

I didn’t know there were multiple definitions

@Jakobian Ah okay

Without $T_1$ you still have that normal Pseudocompact spaces are weakly countably compact: https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000021

Lemma: for any subset $S$ of a $T_1$ space, if $S$ lacks $\omega$-accumulation points, then $S$ is closed and discrete.
Proof: Each point $x$ of the space is not an $\omega$-accumulation point, so there is a neighborhood $U$ that misses all but finitely-many points $F \subseteq S$. $F\setminus\{x\}$ is a closed set by $T_1$, so $U\setminus(F\setminus\{x\})$ is a neighborhood of $x$ missing every point of $S$ distinct from $x$. It follows that $x$ is not a limit point, so $S$ lacks limit points and is discrete. Furthermore, if $x$ belongs to $S$ we see that it is isolated, so $S$ is discrete.

This is actually a characterization of closed and discrete for $T_1$ spaces.
